# Average of pairs (values, weights) in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, average, weighted

Let's say that I have this input data in the form `array = [values, weights]`

```
arr1 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([1,1,1,1])]
arr2 = [np.array([2,4,6,8]), np.array([2,2,2,2])]
```

and what I would like to build pairs of `values` and `weights` ordered entries, and then compute the average ( I hope this is clear from my attempt below).

This is what I've come up with, but it feels like there is a cleaner way of achieving the result:

```
listArrs = [arr1, arr2]

vals = np.array([c[0] for c in listArrs]).T
weights = np.array([c[1] for c in listArrs]).T

[np.average(v,weights=w) for v,w in zip(vals, weights)]

Out: [1.6666666666666667, 3.3333333333333335, 5.0, 6.666666666666667]
```

Comment: From what I know, It appears that you are actually doing the averaging quite efficiently.

Comment: Are you trying to compute the weighted average of the values array? Or the average of the two numbers `[val, weight]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the list comprehension iterator and the zip, just do this -

```
np.average(vals, weights=weights, axis=1)
```

```
array([1.66666667, 3.33333333, 5.        , 6.66666667])
```

Numpy has excellent vectorization and broadcasting implemented so you rarely need iterators when working with matrices or tensors.

Here's a solution without any iterators

```
listArrs = np.array([arr1, arr2])
vals = listArrs[:,0]  #Slice the values
weights = listArrs[:,1]   #Slice the weights
np.average(vals, weights=weights, axis=0)  #Apply a weighted np.average on 2 - 2d arrays
```

```
array([1.66666667, 3.33333333, 5.        , 6.66666667])
```

One liner as you recommended -

```
np.average(listArrs[:,0], weights= listArrs[:,1], axis=0)
```

Comment: great, thanks ! then it could also be abbreviated as: `np.average(listArrs[:,0], weights=listArrs[:,1], axis=0)`